# I want to upload files to the server. (node.js , file upload)

Tags: node.js, file-upload

I want to upload the file to a locally running server.

html form source

```html
<form method="post" action="/plate/add-usb" class="edit-page" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <div class="row">
   
   <div class="col-md-6">
    <label for="file" translate>File From USB</label>
    <select name="USBFile" id="file" class="form-control">
    
     <option value="/media/usb0/8.zip">/media/usb0/8.zip</option>
    
     <option value="/media/usb0/test123.stl">/media/usb0/test123.stl</option>
    
     <option value="/media/usb0/untitled.stl">/media/usb0/untitled.stl</option>
    
    </select>
   </div>
   
   <div class="col-md-6">
    <label for="Path" translate>Plate Name</label>
    <input value="" name="Path" id="Path" class="form-control" required>
    <br>
   </div>
  </div>
  <br>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" translate>Submit</button>
 </form>
```

```html
<form method="post" action="/plate/add-usb" class="edit-page" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <div class="row">
   
   <div class="col-md-6">
    <label for="file" translate>File From USB</label>
    <select name="USBFile" id="file" class="form-control">
    
     <option value="/media/usb0/8.zip">/media/usb0/8.zip</option>
    
     <option value="/media/usb0/test123.stl">/media/usb0/test123.stl</option>
    
     <option value="/media/usb0/untitled.stl">/media/usb0/untitled.stl</option>
    
    </select>
   </div>
   
   <div class="col-md-6">
    <label for="Path" translate>Plate Name</label>
    <input value="" name="Path" id="Path" class="form-control" required>
    <br>
   </div>
  </div>
  <br>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" translate>Submit</button>
 </form>
```

---

The curl command works in the command linux

---

### curl 'http://172.30.1.5/plate/add-usb' -H 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryEKR2KQHVlfoRK7rq' --data-binary $'------WebKitFormBoundaryEKR2KQHVlfoRK7rq\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="USBFile"\r\n\r\n/media/usb0/a8.zip\r\n------WebKitFormBoundaryEKR2KQHVlfoRK7rq\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="Path"\r\n\r\na8\r\n------WebKitFormBoundaryEKR2KQHVlfoRK7rq\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="ProfileID"\r\n\r\n3\r\n------WebKitFormBoundaryEKR2KQHVlfoRK7rq\r\n'

I do not know how to enter the code.
Please write node.js code.

Comment: You are asking [a question that is over your head](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/328017/can-you-ask-a-question-you-know-is-way-over-your-own-head) resp. it is too broad for Stack Overflow

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This is not a code/SQL/regex writing service, where you post a list of your requirements and language of choice and a code monkey churns out code for you. We're more than happy to help, but we expect you to make an effort to solve the problem yourself first. Once you've done so, you can explain the problem you're having, include the **relevant** portions of your work, and ask a specific question, and we'll try to help. Good luck.